# Send & receive Json data between R statistical language and asp.net MVC

Tags: r, model-view-controller

I have an asp.net mvc application from which I need to send `JSON` data with 4-5 fields to **R language** and then receive data back from R. I have read lot many tutorials suggesting to use `Rdotnet` or `RJSON` but, i'm unable to establish link between my application running on IIS and R. Please advise.

Comment: did you look up: http://jmp75.github.io/rdotnet/tut_asp_dot_net/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But unfortunately unable to find a solution yet. Actually my R code creates a model using neural network. The data is then fed to the neural network output to generate the result. So now stuck to use the neural network library in asp.net.

Comment: to get started you might start with a simple example in a non iss application to see how it works. The link I shared before just adresses iss issues - you might connect simple R scripts first with a simple .net console app before you start with more advanced stuff. Here are a few examples:
https://rdotnet.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: I've used `FastRWeb` for this task in the past and it's pretty simple to get up and running. `plumber` is another one that is not on CRAN.